# Return de uma função em outra Classe

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Quero chamar a função `data_hora_atual()` nessa class sessao:

```
class sessao {
    function fazSessao($conexao){

    }
}

class administracao {
    function data_hora_atual($par,$conexao){
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

        return array();
    }
}
```

Comment: class sessao extends administracao  não resolveria ?

Comment: Melhor seria aprender o básico, antes de se aventurar com OO. Por exemplo, corre o risco de sua data se corromper se pegar a virada do dia (ou da hora ou do minuto, seja lá qual for) bem no momento da construção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando que você vá usar o `data_hora_atual` dentro da `fazSessao`, apenas para exemplo:

Duas alternativas:

Transforme a função em estatica:

```
function static data_hora_atual($par,$conexao){ }
```

E na Class sessao:

```
function fazSessao($conexao){
    administracao::data_hora_atual($par, $conexao)
}
```

---

Você também pode extender sua classe administracao:

```
class sessao extends administracao {
    function fazSessao($conexao){
        $this->data_hora_atual($par, $conexao);
    }
}
```

Comment: Você não define um método estático somente para facilitar chamá-lo, você o define quando ele deve ser, de fato, um método estático. Na herança, pior ainda...

Comment: Por favor, explique o que será melhor

Comment: Primeiro, entender o problema, que não está claro na pergunta, para depois propor uma solução. A melhor hipótese do momento seria, se é que isso faz sentido para essa aplicação, criar a instância da classe. Mas sem o problema claro, não há como definir como fazer.

Comment: Desculpa, ao meu ver está claro e objetivo. Obviamente mais detalhes ajudariam, mas em resumo ele quer entender como usar  um método de outra classe, apenas. Sem burocracia, padrões ou boas práticas. Se o que ele precisa é resolver exatamente isso, ambas as alternativas podem ajudar. Se ele quiser avançar, é diferente. Mas consideremos que outras pessoas vem aqui ler, sem entender muito além disso e só precisa resolver.

Comment: Não quero ser rude, não me entenda mal. Mas acredito que não seja legal você fazer uma crítica e não propor uma solução para quem está com dúvida.